# Mapping for Displacement Modifier

Tags: displacement

I'd like to create procedural rocks and so I checked out some tutorial videos. The techniques should be similar, so I also checked out 3ds max tutorials.

This one caught my attention:

[3dsmax Environment Modeling #1 Procedural Stone](https://youtu.be/cr9JcfJjnt4?t=187)

It basically uses a displacement modifier, creates a Voronoi diagram and applies a spherical mapping to the model. These steps look like this:

[image]

**Question**

Does anyone know if Blender has a mapping option for the displacement modifier? I can't find it. Or does anyone know a similar or better approach to create that kind of rocks in Blender?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with a simple cube, add *Subdivision Surface* to produce enough geometry for decent displacing (you can add another one after *Displace* modifier for more smoothing).

Add *Displace* modifier, press *New* button, go into texture tab and select *Voronoi* texture.

In *Displace* modifier settings there are some options for texture coordinates: UV, Local, Global, Object.
There is no usual coordinates offset as in materials, so you need to bind texture to some object. Thus location, rotation and scale of this object will affect texture.

**"Wire sphere" around the rock is *Empty*, which is controlling texture:**
[image]
[image]